# Image not appearing - Bootstrap NavBar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I cannot insert an image into my bootstrap navbar, only my alt screen appears, any idea how to solve this?
Bootstrap: CDN Version 5.0 Beta

Screenshots:
[image]

[image: HTML]
[image: CSS]

Code:

```css
.nav-link{
    color:chartreuse;
    font-family: 'DotGothic16', sans-serif;
}
.navbar-brand{
    color: darkviolet;
}
.nav-item:hover{
    color: chocolate;
}
.navbar-brand:hover{
    color:tomato;
}
.navbar{
    position: sticky;
}
#brand{
    width: 40px;
}
#home{
    position:relative;top:-10px
}
nav{
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark">

        <!-- Links -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="navbar-brand">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32w" fill="currentColor" id="home"
                        class="bi bi-house-door" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path
                            d="M8.354 1.146a.5.5 0 0 0-.708 0l-6 6A.5.5 0 0 0 1.5 7.5v7a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h4.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-4h2v4a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5H14a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-7a.5.5 0 0 0-.146-.354L13 5.793V2.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.293L8.354 1.146zM2.5 14V7.707l5.5-5.5 5.5 5.5V14H10v-4a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v4H2.5z" />
                    </svg>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                    Link 1
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                    Link 2
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                    Link 3
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </nav>
```

***I tried putting it in the internet using imgur.com (Here is the [Imgur Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDhhx.png).) but it still didn't work...
I then used an icon (SVG Format) which I got from [Bootstrap Icons](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/house-door/) and it worked!***

**I inspected using the console window in my browser, it was the right system path. I also resized it wondering if it was the problem but bootstrap usually automatically resizes images to fit in them. I tried using a different browser too.**

Here is the edit I wanted to give :D

Comment: Why are you trying to use a file system path, instead of an actual HTTP URL?

Comment: I tried doing that but same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. try to use root link like src="/path-to-images/image-name"
2. open your image from page by clicking on it in dev console -> open in new tab. the path will be 100% wrong

Comment: In browser or using a console by drag and drop method?

Comment: in browser you can click on image several ways 1) click in page 2) click on element in console -> elements tab . right click will open context menu -> choose open image in new tab

Comment: Thanks for all the help @Andrei Tazetdinov and someone for making me lose my reputation 

Comment: Well it says about:blank#blocked

Comment: hm. make a screen of what you see in console elements if you hover mouse on element with image

Comment: I quit that idea @Andrei but the inspector was leading to the correct image! Crazy isn't it

Comment: maybe first of all you should move your image to the project root and use path from the root to image like src="/some-image-path/image-name" and open file using a live server in vs code. Second thing that you can try to resolve - move your project to the cloud service like Stackblitz for example. Resolve it there and then download or deploy to hosting